# How do you loop through a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

```
foreach (String s in arrayOfMessages)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

`string[,] arrayOfMessages` is being passed in as a parameter.

I want to be able to determine which strings are from `arrayOfMessages[0,i]` and `arrayOfMessages[n,i]`, where `n` is the final index of the array.

Comment: why not just use a loop with indexes then?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simply use two nested `for` loops. To get the sizes of the dimensions, you can use [`GetLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfMessages.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfMessages.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        string s = arrayOfMessages[i, j];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

This assumes you actually have `string[,]`. In .Net it's also possible to have multidimensional arrays that aren't indexed from 0. In that case, they have to be represented as `Array` in C# and you would need to use `GetLowerBound()` and `GetUpperBound()` the get the bounds for each dimension.

Answer (score 11):

With a nested for loop:

```
for (int row = 0; row < arrayOfMessages.GetLength(0); row++)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < arrayOfMessages.GetLength(1); col++)
   {
      string message = arrayOfMessages[row,col];
      // use the message
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `foreach` - use nested `for` loops, one for each dimension of the array.

You can get the number of elements in each dimension with the [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method.

See [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you found an answer suitable for your problem, but since the title asks for a multidimensional array (which I read as 2 *or more*), and this is the first search result I got when searching for that, I'll add my solution:

```
public static class MultidimensionalArrayExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements of the array.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="array">A sequence of values to invoke the action on.</param>
    /// <param name="action">An action to apply to each source element; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.</param>
    public static void ForEach<T>(this Array array, Action<T, int[]> action)
    {
        var dimensionSizes = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank).Select(i => array.GetLength(i)).ToArray();
        ArrayForEach(dimensionSizes, action, new int[] { }, array);
    }
    private static void ArrayForEach<T>(int[] dimensionSizes, Action<T, int[]> action, int[] externalCoordinates, Array masterArray)
    {
        if (dimensionSizes.Length == 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensionSizes[0]; i++)
            {
                var globalCoordinates = externalCoordinates.Concat(new[] { i }).ToArray();
                var value = (T)masterArray.GetValue(globalCoordinates);
                action(value, globalCoordinates);
            }
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensionSizes[0]; i++)
                ArrayForEach(dimensionSizes.Skip(1).ToArray(), action, externalCoordinates.Concat(new[] { i }).ToArray(), masterArray);
    }

    public static void PopulateArray<T>(this Array array, Func<int[], T> calculateElement)
    {
        array.ForEach<T>((element, indexArray) => array.SetValue(calculateElement(indexArray), indexArray));
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var foo = new string[,] { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" } };
foo.ForEach<string>((value, coords) => Console.WriteLine("(" + String.Join(", ", coords) + $")={value}"));
// outputs:
// (0, 0)=a
// (0, 1)=b
// (1, 0)=c
// (1, 1)=d

// Gives a 10d array where each element equals the sum of its coordinates:
var bar = new int[4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5];
bar.PopulateArray(coords => coords.Sum());
```

General idea is to recurse down through dimensions. I'm sure the functions won't win efficiency awards, but it works as a one-off initialiser for my lattice and comes with a nice-enough ForEach that exposes the values and indices. Main downside I haven't solved is getting it to automatically recognise T from the Array, so some caution is required when it comes to the type safety.

Answer (score 2):

A more functional approach would be to use LINQ, which I always find better than loops. It makes the code more maintainable and readable. The below given code snippet shows one of the solution using Method or Fluent LINQ syntax.

```
string[,] arrayOfMessages = new string[3, 2] { { "Col1","I am message 1" }, { "Col2", "I am message 2" }, { "Col3", "I am message 3" } };
var result = arrayOfMessages.Cast<string>()
                            .Where((msg, index) => index % 2 > 0);

foreach (var msg in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

LINQ extension methods are not available to multi-dimensional arrays since they do not implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface. That's where `Cast<T>` comes into picture. It basically casts the whole array into `IEnumerable<T>`. In our case it will flatten out the multi-dimensional array into `IEnumerable<string>` something like:

```
{ "Col1", "I am message 1", "Col2", "I am message 2", "Col3", "I am message 3" }
```

You can also use `OfType<T>` instead of `Cast<T>`. The only difference between them is that in case of collections with mixed data types, while `OfType<T>` ignores values which it is unable to cast, `Cast<T>` will throw an InValidCastException.

Next, all we need to do is to apply a LINQ operator that ignores (or filters out) values at even indices. So we use an overload of `Where` operator whose Func delegate is of the type `Func<TSource, int, bool>`, where `TSource` is each item in the collection, `int` is the index of the item in the collection and `bool` is the return type.

In the above snippet, I used a lambda expression which evaluates each item index and returns true only when it is an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
int length0 = arrayOfMessages.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
int length1 = arrayOfMessages.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

for(int i=0; i<length1; i++) { string msg = arrayOfMessages[0, i]; ... }
for(int i=0; i<length1; i++) { string msg = arrayOfMessages[length0-1, i]; ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to run multidimensional arrays.

```
foreach (String s in arrayOfMessages)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0}",s);
}
```