# C# Multidimenional Array parsing

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array.

The contents look like this in the debugger.

The array is setup as

```
String[,] s = new String[6,4]
```

.

```
A B Yes C
A B Yes C
A B No  C
A B Yes C
A B Yes C
A B Yes C
A B No  C
A B Yes C
```

I basically need to know which row's say No but I am having a tough time parsing the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need 'parsing' then a multidom array is not the best datastructure. Why is it not a `List<MyData>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you loop through a multidimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301109/how-do-you-loop-through-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: This really is already covered by the answers you got yesterday.

Comment: Your sample data shows 4 rows and 4 columns, so it's impossible to tell which array dimension represents the rows and which represents the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so?

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void test()
        {
            var text = new String[6, 4]
                               {
                                   {"A", "B", "C", "Yes"},
                                   {"A", "B", "C", "Yes"},
                                   {"A", "B", "C", "Yes"},
                                   {"A", "B", "C", "Yes"},
                                   {"A", "B", "Not", "C"},
                                   {"A", "B", "C", "Yes"}
                               };
            var rowWithNot = new List<int>();

            for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
                    if (text[row, col].Contains("Not"))
                    {
                        rowWithNot.Add(row);
                        break;
                    }

            foreach (var row in rowWithNot)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(text[row, col]);
                }

            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, s.GetLength(0)).Where(i => s[i, 2] == "No");
```

Comment: This looks really elegant but is rowIndicies an array of Indexs?

Comment: It is an enumerable sequence. Add a ".ToList()" at the end to get a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using something like this :

```
IEnumurable<int> GetRowNumbersThatSayNo(string[,] values)
{
for(int i=0;i<values.Length;i++)
if(values[i,2]=="No") yield return i;
}
```