# how can i declare the matrix in a for loop

Tags: c#

```
for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{
    Xnew[k + 1] = Xold[k] + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Cos(Aold[k]);
    Ynew[k + 1] = Yold[k] + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Sin(Aold[k]);
    Anew[k + 1] = Aold[k] + (T * MPCW[k]);

    Console.WriteLine("\nXnew = {0}", Xnew[k + 1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Ynew = {0}", Ynew[k + 1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Tnew = {0}", Anew[k + 1]);

    double[,] qk = { { Xnew[k + 1] }, { Ynew[k + 1] }, { Anew[k + 1] } };
    Console.WriteLine("the element is {0}", Xnew[k + 1]);
    Console.WriteLine("the element is {0}", Ynew[k + 1]);
    Console.WriteLine("the element is {0}", Anew[k + 1]);
}
```

For the above code, if I were to set qk(k) as a new matrix every time k changes. Is there anyway to do it? I tried declaring as `double[,] qk[k] = { { Xnew[k + 1] }, { Ynew[k + 1] }, { Anew[k + 1] } };` but it didn't work.

An example will be when my k increases, my value of Xnew, ynew and anew will also changes with k. hence, i would declare q(k) which k will increase as k increase and store the value xnew ynew and anew.

Comment: Hope [loop through a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9301175/3796048) will englighten you more to declare the matrix in a for loop

Comment: your declaration is wrong as per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).Should it not be `double[,] qk = new double[,] { { Xnew[k + 1] }, { Ynew[k + 1] }, { Anew[k + 1] } };`..

Comment: Do you want to access `qk` outside of your current loop iteration? Also, is it correct that you want a collection of matrices, where each matrix is accessible by its index `k` and the dimension of each matrix is 3x1 ?

Comment: Actually i am doing a MPC controller programming. i need my qK as my k increase. So for instance, when k =1, i will have qk[1] and store the value as a matrix as [X[2] Y[2] and A[2]] and when my k=2 i will have qk[2] and store as a matrix as [X[2] Y[2] and A[2]]. With this matrix, i will also do a matrix subtraction with another 3 by 1 matrix outside of this for loop with another loop. Sorry if i explanation is unclear.

Comment: @weixiang Well sorry, but it is unclear to me even now. Also, please edit your question with additional information instead of writing it into the comments.