# Jagged array is not displayed

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I was playing with jagged arrays and I created  one dimensional integer jagged array with a 3  two-dimensional arrays inside of him.I want to display my jagged array but when I run the code I get Exception Unhandled.It writes that index of my elements in array get out of range.I think there is a problem in determining the length of the array in the counter, that is, the problem of how long the counter should count.

```
int[][,] a = new int[3][,] {
    new int[,]{ { 1,2},{ 3,4}},
    new int[,]{ {65,10 },{7,8 }},
    new int[,]{{5,6},{86,31}, }
};
for(int i = 0; i <a[i].Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.tabel",(i+1));

    for(int k = 0; k < a[k].Length; k++)
    {    //*This is the place where I get an exception
         Console.Write(a[i][i,k]);
    }
}
```

My goal is to make the program output look like this :

```
1. tabel
1 2
3 4
2. tabel
65 10
7 8
3. tabel
5 6
86 31
```

P.S. I write the comment at the place where I get unexception unhandled
Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to use `GetLength` for iterating over the two-dimensional arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301109/how-do-you-loop-through-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 3 dimensions you need 3 nested loops. Also, if an array has more than one dimension, you must use `GetLenth(dimension)` and specify the dimension number (0 based):

```
int[][,] a = new int[3][,] {
    new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } },
    new int[,] { { 65, 10 }, { 7, 8 } },
    new int[,] { { 5, 6 }, { 86, 31 }, }
};
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) { // Loop over a[i]
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. tabel");
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].GetLength(0); j++) { // Loop over a[][j,]
        Console.Write("   ");
        for (int k = 0; k < a[i].GetLength(1); k++) { // Loop over a[][,k]
            Console.Write($" {a[i][j, k]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

`a[i].Length` for a `[n, m]` sized array yields `n * m`.

It gets a bit clearer if you assign the inner array to a local variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) { // Loop over a[i]
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. tabel");
    int[,] matrix = a[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0); j++) { // Loop over matrix[j,]
        Console.Write("  ");
        for (int k = 0; k < matrix.GetLength(1); k++) { // Loop over matrix[,k]
            Console.Write($" {matrix[j, k]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```